# Why power set of $\Omega$ (set of all outcomes) can't always be used as field in probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P$)?

Tags: probability-theory

I guess it's because, for example, when $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ (denote its size as $|\mathbb{R}|$), its *power set* would be too large, with its size equals $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$, and though we can find a nowhere zero function $f$ of domain as large as $\mathbb{R}^n$, ${\{0,1\}}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is too much larger than $\mathbb{R}^n$ that we can't find $f$ such that $\int_{2^{\mathbb{R}}} f= 1$.

Because probability for a continuous variable is $0$ at all points and this fact would make things confusing, let me make change the discussion to one on a discrete variable.

By dissecting ${\mathbb{R}}$ into countable ($|\mathbb{N}|$) closed intervals, we dissect ${\{0,1}\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ into a collection $X$ of $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ closed intervals,  We can regard the integral as 'infinite' ($O(2^{N})$, larger than the size of a typical inf series ) series $\sum_{q\in {\{0,1\}}^{\mathbb{N}}} a_q$, where $a_q$ is probability of $q$th closed intervals $\delta \omega_q$ in $X$, and $a_q= \int_{\delta \omega_q}f$. So the hypothesis in the last paragraph can be rephrased as we can't find we can't find a function $a(q)$ of $q$ such that $\sum_{{\{0,1\}}^{\mathbb{N}}} a(q) = 1$.

Well, I myself think this reasoning is flawed.  Perhaps we can define $\{a_q\}$ to be a sequence that converges so fast that the inf series $\sum a_q$ converges even if there are uncountable items to be summed. Is that right?

Or perhaps the reason is not as above, but that if we let the power set be set $\mathcal{F}$ of events , it would cause contradictions in calculating probability of intersections/unions of events?

Comment: I mean... you *could* use the power-set algebra, but it doesn't always carry the probability measures you care about. The classical example is that, accepting the axiom of choice, there is no uniform measure on the power set of $[0,1]$.

Comment: As for the uncountable sum thing, defining $\sum_{i \in I} a_i=\sup_{F\subseteq I, |F|<\infty}\sum_{i\in F} a_i$ for positive $a_i$, you get that $\sum_{i\in I} a_i=\infty$ unless $a_i=0$ for all but countably many $i$ simply by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I seem to understand why there is no uniform measure in this example, since $\int_{[0,q]^\infty} const =1$ only when const is infinity (if 0<q<1) or zero (if q>1) (though I don’t know why const can’t be non zero if q=1); and if an event is of probability 0 then it doesn’t mean much to include the event in $\mathcal{F}$. But why would we prefer  $\mathcal{F}$ to allow uniform measure? For example, the outcome space $\Omega$ of Gaussian distribution is $\mathbb{R}$ and don’t allow uniform distribution and it’s still commonly used?

Comment: My guess is that for Gaussian distribution, outcome space seems can only be defined as $\mathbb{R}$ and that if we require all events to be of probability non zero, then the set of events seems to include all open intervals (and not real numbers), and so  $\mathcal{F}$ is much smaller than the power set of  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (And any event will have at most countably many connected open intervals instead of open intervals plus uncountably many real numbers, otherwise all but the countably many intervals will have probability zero (I.e. probability of a points in continuous distribution is zero) and so too trivial to be included in this event. ) This seems to explain why we sometimes had better not use the power set as event space?

Comment: There also isn't any Gaussian measure on the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ or indeed any non-zero measure with density with respect to the Lesbegue measure. As for the rest, I have no clue what you mean. A general Borel set can look very weird - it's not, in general, a union of intervals in any sense. And you seem to think that singletons are not in the Borel algebra, but they very much are. The subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not Borel are bizarre, such as the Vitali set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). No subset of $\mathbb{R} that you're ever gonna write down is gonna be non-Borel.